# How to include current folder name in Git log

Tags: git, git-log

I'm writing a script to loop over all Git repositories in a certain folder and its subfolders and execute `git log`.
The output of the script is eventually saved to a CSV log file.

Now I want to include the current folder name in the git-log result, but I can't find how to do this in the [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation.

My current git-log command looks like this:

```
git log --branches=master --no-merges --pretty=format:"%H;%an;%ad;%s" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: maybe misunderstanding the question, but why dont you print the folder name using the scripting language you're using?

Comment: as far as i can see, there's no placeholder for the format string to have repo name / folder name.

Comment: `git log foldername/filename` is this what you want?

Comment: I tried that, but I want the folder name shown for every commit. But the git-log result can output multiple commits. And then the folder name would only be shown for the first commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong tool for the task. The current directory is a property of the environment, not of the repository; `git log` doesn't care very much about it.

Accordingly, you should get the current directory in the script and put it somehow into the output of `git log`.

If you need to have the repo directory on each line returned by `git log` then you can simply squeeze `$(pwd)` inside the format string:

```
git log --branches=master --no-merges --pretty=format:"%H;%an;%ad;%s;$(pwd)" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

Be warned that it will produce undesired results if the current path contains `%` because it is a special character interpreted by `git log`.

To avoid this happen you can use `sed` to escape the `%` characters before inserting the path into the format:

```
dir=$(pwd | sed s/%/%%/g)
git log --branches=master --no-merges --pretty=format:"%H;%an;%ad;%s;$dir" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

It can still produce problems if the current path contains `"` or `;` as they are special characters for both the shell and the CSV format. You can try to quote them too in the `sed` command, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure if I understand correctly, but are you searching for --dirstat ?:

this will add a percentage of changes for each changed directory at the bottom of the commit message. From the manpage:

> ```
>    --dirstat[=<param1,param2,...>]
>        Output the distribution of relative amount of changes for each sub-directory. The behavior of --dirstat can be customized by
>        passing it a comma separated list of parameters. The defaults are controlled by the diff.dirstat configuration variable (see git-
>        config(1)). The following parameters are available:
> ```